How to prevent bubbling to the document in Vue 3?
I am developing a Vue 3 component, which will be referenced by a larger project after being packaged into a JS file. However, this project has a focusin listener set on the document, and this listener is negatively affecting the a-textarea component in the Vue 3 component I am working on.
I am not allowed to make any changes to this listener. During debugging, I noticed that the negative effect disappears when I remove the focus or focusin listener from the elements in the browser’s event listener tab. However, simply removing the code inside the listener without removing the listener itself does not eliminate the negative effect. I personally believe that the bubbling of focusin is the root cause of the issue, but I am unable to stop it from bubbling in the Vue file, as the event bound on document has already executed before I can prevent it from bubbling. Below is the situation I replicated in the local environment.
  <a-modal v-model:open="isModalVisible" :title="title" @ok="handleOk" @cancel="handleCancel" :zIndex="1500">
    <div ref="textareaDiv" class="ant-textarea-general" style="height: auto"
      @focusin.capture="(event) => { event.stopPropagation(); console.log('happened2') }" >
      
      <a-textarea ref="myTextarea" v-model:value="textareaValue" :rows="8" allowClear :maxLength="maxlength"
        @focus.capture="(event) => { event.stopImmediatePropagation(); event.stopPropagation(); console.log('happened focus') }">
      </a-textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="ant-form-extra">
      {{ modalPlaceholder }}
    </div>
  </a-modal>

    onMounted(() => {
      const module0Store = useModule0Store();
      module0Store.loading = false;

      const textareaDiv = useTemplateRef('textareaDiv');
      console.log("textareaDiv", textareaDiv);

      const stopWatching = watch(isModalVisible, () => {
        nextTick(() => {
          console.log("textareaDiv", textareaDiv);
          (textareaDiv.value as any).addEventListener('focusin', () => { console.log("1111") }, true);
        });
        stopWatching();
      });

in the html
 $(document).on('focusin', function(event) {
     console.log('the element received focus: ', event.target);
 });


I hope to prevent focusin from bubbling to the document after the a-textarea gains focus, without affecting components outside the a-modal. Currently, I can only watch helplessly as the focusin function bound to the document triggers first, followed by my function that prevents the bubbling.

This is an issue that can be easily reproduced in just a few steps:

Use npm create vue@latest to create a Vue project (no additional features are needed).

In the created project, find index.html and add the following:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('focusin', function(event) {
        console.log('the element received focus: ', event.target);
    });
  })
</script>


In App.vue, add the following:
<input style="width: 200px;" @focusin.stop="() => { console.log('I can't stop it') }" />



These are the complete reproduction steps. Now you can see the reason for my frustration.

I have created a GitHub repository for this issue, which contains a simple reproduction of the problem here.
I am still a beginner in using Vue.

Can't you use .stop? https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

The function of using .stop and event.stopPropagation(); is the same. I have tried both, but neither has any effect. @kissu
